# Puppet - using hiera parameters in a top scope manifest file

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a site.pp file which looks like this:

```
Package {allow_virtual => false,}

stage { 'pre': before => Stage['main'] }
stage { 'post': require => Stage['main'] }

resources { 'firewall': purge => true }

node default {
  hiera_include('classes')
}
```

I’d like to be able to set the firewall purge line based on the value of a hiera parameter.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of puppet you're using but this should work with any recent version .  Add this to hiera:

```
firewall::purge: true
```

Then modify your site.pp like this:

```
if hiera('firewall::purge') {
    resources { 'firewall': purge => true } 
}
```